# Start VMs in different resource groups using azure CLI

Tags: azure, command-line-interface

Is there a way to start VMs from different resource groups using azure CLI?

For VMs in the same resource group, I know the following command according to [this post](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-cli-arm-commands/):

`vm start [options] <resource-group> <name>`

I think another way is to first move the VMs into the same resource group. But my VMs are deployed using `Resource manager mode` and only those via `classic mode` can be moved to the same resource group, according to [this post](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-move-resources/#services-that-support-move).

Comment: Why do you want to do this? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Michael B I found that ```vm start [options] <resource-group> <name>``` can only launch one VM inside one resource-group. Do you know how can I launch all VMs inside the same resource group at once? Thanks!

Comment: In PowerShell you would list all the VMs in a resource group and then pipe them to the vm start command, I'm not sure how that works in CLI, but I imagine it is similar (it might be worth a new question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is No. This isn't possible.

The reason that you specify the resource group and the vmname is because that is how every VM is identified. You can have identically configured VMs (with the same name) that the only difference between them is the resource group.

If you look under the covers at how things are identified, you have something like this

```
/subscriptions/{subscriptionid}/resourceGroups/{resourcegroupname}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{vmname}
```

This way every virtual machine across the entire Azure infrastructure can be uniquely identified.

When you interact with a vm you add commands to the end of that Id. So a reboot becomes something like

```
~/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{vmname}/reboot
```

That's not the exact command, but you get the idea hopefully, and understand why that's not possible.